# Nginx rewrite rule affects all subfolders

Tags: nginx

How can I change a rewrite rule so that it affects only folder 01:

```
/01/01.png
/02/02.png
```

If is used one of this three rewrite rules

```
rewrite /(.*(png))$ /01/$1 last;
rewrite /(.*)$ /01/$1 last;
rewrite ^ /01/$uri last;
```

the file /01/01.png can be opened directly through /01.png (that was the goal of the rewrite rule) but now the file /02/02.png can't be opened any more as usually, nginx shows only "404 Not Found". Also png files in all other subfolders can't be opened any more. How the rewrite rule must be changed so that it affects only folder 01? I'm new to nginx and can't find a solution, please can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried this: `rewrite ^/01/(.*)$ /01/$1 last;` ?

Comment: So the file /01/01.png can't be opened directly through /01.png

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for the problem, now I use a second rewrite rule for other folders with jpg-files. Many Greetings